# Using the call '&' operator with multiple parameters

Tags: powershell, exe

```
            $sImageMagickHome = "C:\ImageMagick"
            $sImageMagickConv = "$sImageMagickHome\convert.exe"
            $sImageMagickArgs = @(  '--%', 
                            '-background transparent', 
                            '-fill hsb(0,0,0)', 
                            '-font Arial',
                            '-pointsize 18',
                            '-size 18x26',
                            '-gravity center')


            for ( $i = 0x01; $i -le 0x05; $i++ )
            {
                $y = [char]$i
                & $sImageMagickConv $sImageMagickArgs label:$y $sCharsDir\$y.png
                #Write-Host $sImageMagickConv $sImageMagickArgs label:$y $sCharsDir\$y.png
            }
```

Using Write-Host I can get an example to copy paste into the command line and I find it does run correctly if I run this single line from the PowerShell prompt:

```
C:\ImageMagick\convert.exe --% -background transparent -fill hsb(0,0,0) -font Arial -pointsize 18 -size 18x26 -gravity center label:☺ C:\Users\erics_000\Desktop\Output\Chars\☺.png
```

Using the call operator '&' from inside the script does not work at all however and leads to some error messages:

```
convert.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `--%': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2697.
convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: UnrecognizedOption `-background transparent' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/858.
```

The article I have been reading is:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Thank you...

Comment: Did you try removing `--%` from your args array? I think it only makes sense if added verbatim to the call, not passed through variable.

Comment: The --% is there because it will not run on the PowerShell prompt without the --%. Removing the --% from the arguments array leads to a different problem. convert.exe: UnrecognizedOption `-background transparent' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/858.

Comment: Well, `-background` and `transparent` should be different array items as `convert.exe` expects them to be. With your current code powershell produces single `-background transparent` (as if you put quotes around it) argument.

Comment: The problem I have now is an unable to open blob having to do with the output file parameter which contains the full path. http://pastebin.com/NswmzR4A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script works for me:

```
$sImageMagickHome = "C:\dev\im"
$sImageMagickConv = "$sImageMagickHome\convert.exe"
$sImageMagickArgs = @('-background', 'transparent', 
                '-fill', 'hsb(0,0,0)', 
                '-font', 'Arial',
                '-pointsize', '18',
                '-size', '18x26',
                '-gravity', 'center')


for ( $i = 65; $i -le 67; $i++ )
{
    $y = [char]$i
    & $sImageMagickConv $sImageMagickArgs label:$y c:\dev\$y.bmp
}
```

Note that you cannot just `Write-Host` the arguments and try running it from command line, Powershell does special processing for `&` operator (adds quotes where needed), which it does not when you pass same arguments to `Write-Host`.

You'd probably want to install [PSCX](https://pscx.codeplex.com/releases) and play around with `echoargs` utility bundled with it to gain better understanding of how arguments are passed.

Comment: I placed your array in the script the problem now is an unable to open blob. http://pastebin.com/NswmzR4A. The output parameter contains the full path to the file and is causing the script to break down.

Comment: Does it fail if you run the script (i.e. not paste command into command line)?

Comment: When you run it manually, you need to add `--%` or quote arguments appropriately. When you run with `&` operator and pass array Powershell does quoting for you.

Comment: The quotes inside the script on the & line don't matter it doesn't work with or without those quotes. This command so far will only run from the PowerShell prompt with the use of --% and that's it. The problem now is the output parameter it will not accept the full path in script.

Comment: I tried using @ to specify the full path. I have not had any luck like that yet.

Comment: When I use the --% on the PowerShell prompt the output file goes into the correct full path directory. From the script with the use of & using the full path breaks down the script.

Comment: See updates. You need to understand that whatever you print with `Write-Host` is *not* the same as how powershell calls `convert.exe`.

Comment: I understand and I hear what you have told me about how & quotes automatically however I am not able to get the last parameter to feed through as it contains a full path to the output file which is a png. I think based off of what you are telling me I have to do a conversion to string from char perhaps but I'm still grasping at straws.

Comment: It does not matter whether you put relative or full path as the last arguments. Characters you use though might not be acceptable for file names though. See my update, it still works.

Comment: For the benefit of others I would like to say you were correct and the character code is not the way to tag the file name. http://pastebin.com/iXhnA9Bc